# Gazebo: Assertion `msSingleton' failed

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic

I have installed gazebo following [this tutorial](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu) on Ubuntu 20.04 and everything went fine during the installation. But when I input the `gazebo` command in the terminal, I met this error.

```
gzserver: /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreRoot.cpp:105: static Ogre::Root& Ogre::Root::getSingleton(): Assertion `msSingleton' failed.
```

I have searched this error online but got nothing. Could you help me solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please check if there is more information in the ~/.gazebo/ogre.log directory?

Comment: Hi! @JoseLuisRivero Inspired by your comment, I checked the ogre.log file, in which the last line shows that RenderSystem_GL.so is being loaded from the path to conda env lib. So, I think the reason for this is that I didn't  `source ~/.bashrc` after deactivating the conda env. I also reopen a terminal and retry the `roslaunch` step, after which everything goes fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help !